# Radio button does not work - state is not changing

Tags: html, css

I am using a tutorial which is teaching me how to make custom radio buttons. My problem is that when I made 3 radio buttons, only first one is working. It is not possible to click on another two. When I click another one, only the first button is working.

HTML:

```
    <label for="myRadioId" class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input">
      <div class="radio__radio"></div>
      option 1
    </label><br>
    <label for="myRadioId" class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input">
      <div class="radio__radio"></div>
    option 2
    </label><br>
    <label for="myRadioId" class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input" disabled>
      <div class="radio__radio"></div>
     disabled
    </label>
```

CSS:

```css
    .radio {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-flex;
    }


    .radio__input {
      display: none;
    }

    .radio__radio {
      width: 1.25rem;
      height: 1.25rem;
      border: 2px solid #d8e4e2;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-right: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 2px;
    }

    .radio__radio::after {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      background: #009879;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: transform 0.15s;
    }

    .radio__input:checked + .radio__radio::after {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
```

[image: Here is how it looks like, only top radio button works]

Does anybody have any idea for what to do to make the radio buttons start working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A `<label>` with a `for` attribute will, when clicked, toggle the corresponding checkbox/radiobutton with the same `id`.
- A radio button, when checked, will uncheck all other radio buttons with the same `name`.
- IDs must be unique.

Now, all your radio buttons have *the same ID*. Apart from being invalid, this also has the consequence that clicking any radio button at all (since they are all inside a `<label>` with `for="myRadioId"`) will attempt to click to the radio button with ID `myRadioId`. Your first radio button matches, so it gets clicked. (It doesn't matter that the other two would match as well, because IDs are supposed to exist only once!)

The solution: Use different IDs for each radio button:

```html
<label for="myRadioId1" class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId1" class="radio__input">
  <div class="radio__radio"></div>
  option 1
</label><br>
<label for="myRadioId2" class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId2" class="radio__input">
  <div class="radio__radio"></div>
option 2
</label><br>
<label for="myRadioId3" class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId3" class="radio__input" disabled>
  <div class="radio__radio"></div>
 disabled
</label>
```

(Also, they'll probably need a `value` too, so that you can know which one was clicked at the end by looking at the form data.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need change id of every input tag as well as label 'for' attribute then it will work perfectly.
like : 
label for="link1" & input id="link1" 
label for="link2" & input id="link2" 
label for="link3" & input id="link3"